# How do I restart a scheduled thread if an exception occurs?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am running a thread that is scheduled to run every 10 milliseconds with a ScheduledExecutorService. Sometimes the thread fails because of a random uncaught exception, and I wanted to know how to restart the thread when this happens. I tried to make the thread global, and check if the thread was alive using another scheduled thread, but that always returns false even when it it running. I also tried to check the state of the global thread, but that always returned "NEW". Any help would be much appreciated!
Here is the code that initializes everything:

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(4);
Thread update = new Thread(new UpdateThread());
scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(update, 0, 10, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Comment: Simple solution, put a try{}catch(Exception e){} around everything the thread runs..

Comment: Question is why the thread would fail in the first place no ? Would you mind posting a little bit of your code ? I mean it would be better to understand why it fails so that you don't even have to check whether it is alive or not no ? Using a try catch would probably help getting the reason why it fails ;-) ! You can then edit your answer with that or preferably ask a new question I would say

Comment: What do you mean _random uncaught exception_?? Why do you have **random** and **uncaught** exceptions? Have you tried _catching_ them? Also, 10 milliseconds might be a little tight...

Comment: 'random uncaught exception' - you have a hardware problem?  If so, you should fix it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whatever runnable you're passing to the ExecutorService should just have its body in a `try{} catch (RuntimeException) {/*log it*/}` block.  The Javadoc for `ScheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate` explicitly says that if the scheduled Runnable throws an exception, future executions are suppressed.

If for some reason you don't want to wrap the body in a try/catch - you can use the `ScheduledFuture` returned by `scheduleAtFixedRate`; based on my quick testing, calling `get` on that ScheduledFuture will block until any execution of the task fails with an uncaught exception.

As an aside - you generally shouldn't pass a `Thread` to an `ExecutorService`; the service just takes a `Runnable`, and creates its own `Thread`s internally.

Comment: actually, the `scheduleAtFixedRate` method doesn't have a `Callable` override.

Comment: @BoristheSpider: damn, so I have. Already up-voted the answer though when I commented, so hopefully I'm absolved.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels No hard feelings :-)